# SQL Server 2008 IIF statement does not seem enabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to use `IIF()` in a select statement. The boolean expression checks to see if a fields value is equal to an empty string. The syntax is like so:

```
SELECT IIF(field = '','ONe action','Another')
```

I am getting the error "syntax error near ="

I tried a simple test:

```
SELECT IIF(2 > 1, 'yes','no')
```

and I am getting `"syntax errror near >"`

This is leading me to believe that `IIF` is not working at all.

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2, is there something that needs to be configured to allow IIF() to work? Is there something about the syntax that I am missing? My test is simple as can be and I still get the syntax error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As noted, `IIF` is a SQL2012 feature.

Replace your `IIF` with a `CASE` ( Which is what SQL 2012 would do anyway )

```
 SELECT CASE field WHEN '' THEN 'ONe action' ELSE 'Another' END
```

Answer (score 32):

`IFF` is available starting from SQL Server 2012. So use 'Case' instead.

**If you are looking for a more compact form** (function instead of case) in SQL Server 2008 you can use:

```
isnull((select 'yes' where 2 > 1),'no')
```

instead of:

```
SELECT IIF(2 > 1, 'yes','no')
```

Then your statement will be:

`SELECT isnull((select 'yes' where 2 > 1),'no')`

Answer (score 14):

`IIF` was [introduced in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx), so that is why it does not work in SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @a int=45

DECLARE @b int=40

SELECT   
      CASE 
         WHEN @A>@B THEN 'True'

 ELSE 'FALSE'         
      END
```

You can use this solution instead of `IIF`.