# IIF(...) not a recognized built-in function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to use this in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SET @SomeVar = @SomeOtherVar +
  IIF(@SomeBool, 'value when true', 'value when false')
```

But I get an error:

> `IIF(...)` is not a recognized built-in function name

Is [`IIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) only compatible with a later version?

Is there an alternate function I can use?

Comment: Most pages of BOL have an "Other Versions" link/drop-down below the title if the item has existed in previous versions. Given the absence on this page, I'd say it's a 2012 feature only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 IIF statement does not seem enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540753/sql-server-2008-iif-statement-does-not-seem-enabled)

Comment: `IIF()` is an MS Access function.  The `case` statements described in the answers are the ANSI standard way of doing conditional statements.

Comment: Note to dopes like me: Ensure you didn't type `IFF` in place of `IIF`. Two ayes have it. One does not.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`IIF` comes from SQL 2012.  Before then, you can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SET @SomeVar = @SomeOtherVar + CASE
 WHEN @SomeBool
 THEN 'value when true'
 ELSE 'value when false'
END
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use 'IFF' in SQL 2014, however, I am getting the same error - "IFF' is not a recognized built-in function name." 
Was it discontinued in SQL 2014...?

MSDN exclusively mentions only SQL 2012. 
( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: The function is `IIF`, not `IFF`.  Otherwise, check the Compatibility Level setting on your database.

Comment: @Richard This gets me every time

Comment: @Richard 7-1/2 years later and you just saved my butt. Freakin' typos get me every time... I always miss some mundane detail.

Answer (score 9):

What's New in SQL Server 2012, [Programmability Enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645577):

> SQL Server 2012 introduces 14 new built-in functions. These functions ease the path of migration for information workers by emulating functionality that is found in the expression languages of many desktop applications. However these functions will also be useful to experienced users of SQL Server.
>
> ...
>
> - [IIF (Transact SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574)

Answer (score 4):

`IIF` is **not** valid for SQL Server 2008 R2 and any version before that.

[`IIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) was introduced in SQL Server 2012 (there is no link to previous versions on the documentation page I have linked to).

Comment: I've been using IIF in SQL Server for 20+ years. But can't get it to work on SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the standard IF statement if it's outside a select.

E.g.

```
DECLARE @Answer VARCHAR(3) = 'YES'

IF @Answer = 'Yes'
BEGIN 
--Do Something if true
END
ELSE
-- Do Soemthing if false
```