# IIF function - SQL Server 2008 analogue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this SQL code written for SQL Server 2012 and working fine there:

```
select 
    d.sp_id, 
    sum(iif(d.Published is null, 0, 1)) as Published,
    sum(iif(d.Cancelled is null, 0, 1)) as Cancelled,
    sum(iif(d.Revenue is null, 0, d.Revenue)) as Revenue
from
    [MyTable] d
group by 
    d.sp_id
```

Here `Published` and `Cancelled` are `datetime` values.

The `Revenue` is a `decimal(18,8)` value.

I need to migrate it to SQL Server 2008 R2 (where `IIF` is not available).

What is the best way of doing this? (while preserving its logic at 100%).

I can think of using `CASE` but this sounds too verbose to me.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `CASE d.Published WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: @Habib This is what I was thinking of, yes. But as said, sounds somehow too verbose to me.

Comment: You know that `IIF` is just syntactic sugar, it translates into `CASE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IIF` function is just syntactic sugar, it translates into a CASE statement.
In versions of SQL Server before 2012, use `CASE` instead of `IIF`.

See also:

[IIF(...) not a recognized built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035062/iif-not-a-recognized-built-in-function)