# SQL Server: Use different date format in Select when selected date equals current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select

I have a table with a column "`modTime`" formatted as datetime. 
To fetch dates from this column I use the following line in my Select which returns a date in the format DD MMM YYYY:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), G.modTime, 106) AS modTime
```

Is there a way that I can return the date in a different format (like the following) when it matches the current date and only otherwise use the above format ? This returns the date as Today at hh:mm.

```
('Today at ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), G.modTime, 108)) AS modTime
```

Both ways work when I use them separately but I couldn't find a way to combine them using CASE etc.

Comment: This strikes me as something that should probably be done UI-side by your code, rather than loaded onto SQL. It's not a bad question, but you might want to reconsider your architecture if you need to do this in T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I can do it in PHP as well but I wasn't sure what is the better approach here.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen you are right, but I think doing this at database side might give us some performance benefits at UI-side.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought as well, esp. as I have to do this for multiple dates in one select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not match to getdate() using equals, and you need to set getdate()'s time to midnight

```
select
      case when G.modTime >= dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0)
                then ('Today at ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), G.modTime, 108)) 
           else
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), G.modTime, 106)
      end  AS modTime
from G
```

Above I have used: dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() )

Instead you could use: cast(getdate() as date)

both, have the effect of giving you "today" at 00:00:00

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
select iif(G.modTime=getdate(),('Today at ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), G.modTime, 108)),CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),G.modTime, 106) ) from <table name>
```

Please note that IIF works only with SQL Server 2012 or later.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx

For older versions, this post might help you:

[SQL Server 2008 IIF statement does not seem enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540753/sql-server-2008-iif-statement-does-not-seem-enabled)

Comment: Thanks for this ! I use SQL Server 2008 so the above wouldn't work but I'll check the link you provided.