# IIF 'Incorrect syntax near' error at SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, iif

I am trying date control by month with this script

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2015-07-31';
DECLARE @MonthCount INT = 3;
DECLARE @controlDate DATETIME = '2015-04-28';

SELECT
    MONTH(@controlDate),
    MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -@MonthCount, @Date)),
    IIF(MONTH(@controlDate) > MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -@MonthCount, @Date)),'OK','No') as isOK
```

But I am getting this syntax error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near '>'

[image]

EDIT:
When I try `if` it is working:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2015-07-31';
DECLARE @MonthCount INT = 3;
DECLARE @controlDate DATETIME = '2015-04-28';

if(MONTH(@controlDate) > MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -@MonthCount, @Date)))
print 'OK'
else
print 'No'
```

What am I doing wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I believe you need the `case` syntax here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/63480/60188

Comment: @AntonGogolev but i am not want use case. IIF is more simple.

Comment: @eMKey - Its working here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ffa43/4

Comment: @Fireblade Look that => [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/5md0xz.jpg)

Comment: @eMKey - Yeah i see that. What's the compatibility level of your database

Comment: @Fireblade How to set compability level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you're not running on a correct version of SQL Server, or if the compatibility level of the database isn't set sufficiently.

To check compatibility level:

```
select compatibility_level 
from sys.databases 
where name = '<database name>'
```

To alter compatibility level:

```
alter database <database-name> 
set compatibility level = 110 -- SQL Server 2012
```

List of compatibility levels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Comment: My compability level is 90. For sql server 2014 what is compability level?

Comment: Seems like 120 is the value for 2014, see link in updated answer.

Comment: I am getting error for 120 => Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
 Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: But at about writing sql server 2014

Comment: @thebjorn - `IIF` was introduced in `sql server 2012`

Comment: My bad.  @Fireblade is correct. `IIF` was introduced in sqlserver 2012. You'll have to upgrade (or use `case`).

Comment: @Fireblade Thanks I will upgrade Sql server but did you see the picture on the link at before your comment?

Comment: @eMKey - yes i saw by clicking at the ZOOM button in that page

Comment: The ssms version can be different from the database version (you can connect to a 2008R2 database from ssms 2014 like you're doing without any issues).  It's the db version that is important for which sql syntax is legal though.

Answer (score 2):

It should work correctly. You can also use CASE expression

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2015-07-31';
DECLARE @MonthCount INT = 3;
DECLARE @controlDate DATETIME = '2015-04-28';

SELECT
    MONTH(@controlDate),
    MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -@MonthCount, @Date)),
    case when MONTH(@controlDate) > 
    MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -@MonthCount, @Date)) then 'OK' else 'No' end as isOK
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because `IIF` was introduced in SQL Server 2012 but my client used 2008R2. Use `case` instead: [SQL Server 2008 IIF statement does not seem enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540753/sql-server-2008-iif-statement-does-not-seem-enabled)