# How to convert Access SQL code with IIf() functions to T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

I am rewriting code from MS Access to T-SQL (SQL Server 2008 R2) and this one had me stumped. I know I would need to use the `CASE ... WHEN` statement but this one is involving many columns and then count those that have '0's.

```
IIf(S.Knowledge1=0,1,0) +IIf(S.Routing1=0,1,0) +IIf(S.DataEntry1=0,1,0) +IIf(S.DataEntry2=0,1,0) +IIf(S.DataEntry3=0,1,0) +IIf(S.Scripting1=0,1,0) +IIf(S.Conduct1=0,1,0) +IIf(S.Conduct2=0,1,0) +IIf(S.Conduct3=0,1,0) AS CoachingCount
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not a code translation service. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: That link you provided does NOT help me at all for what I am needing help with. And I have had a couple questions similar to my question above in StackOverFlow helped me in the past. Thanks!

Comment: And Marc, please read my post a little slower and this link.....IIF doesn't work for 2008R2...it's new starting with 2012.........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540753/sql-server-2008-iif-statement-does-not-seem-enabled

Comment: Holly, please have a try with `CASE ... WHEN`, show us how far you get, and describe any problem you encounter.  Here is a starter: `select case when s.DataEntry1=0 then 1 else 0 end + case when s.DataEntry2=0 then 1 else 0 end AS CoachingCount FROM table1 AS s`

Comment: HansUp - BINGO! Just did all the 16 columns exactly how you explained and it came out perfect. Thank you ! This one is NEW for me. Never knew that one can + the case whens together.  Need to mark your answer as the right one somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct is correct that `CASE ... WHEN` would be useful.  But don't think in terms of one massive `CASE ... WHEN` expression as a substitute for all those Access `IIf` expressions.  Instead use a separate `CASE ... WHEN` for each `IIf` ... and sum up their values as you did with the `IIf` expressions.

Here is a brief example based on only 2 of those fields to get you started:

```sql
select
      case when s.DataEntry1=0 then 1 else 0 end
    + case when s.DataEntry2=0 then 1 else 0 end AS CoachingCount
FROM table1 AS s
```