# isnull(@variable, 1) but for 0 instead of null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an equation that multiplies loads of variables together, if one of those variables is 0 then I don't want it included in the equation by substituting it for 1 which won't affect the result.

A case when - then, statement for each variable validating if they're greater than 0is a bit clunky.

Is there a similar function like IsNull where if the variable is 0 then it returns an alternate value?

--edit @Backs answer is right but apparently after sql 2012 iif was taken out, when i try to write the statement there is a syntax error at the '=' sign. Is there a replacement for iif after sql-2012?

Comment: A bit clunky: `ISNULL(NULLIF(x,0), 1)`, or `IIF(x=0,1,x)`

Comment: You say using CASE would "take too long", what do you mean by this? Do you mean that the performance of evaluating comparison to 0 will be too slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IIF(@variable = 0, 1, @variable)
```

Comment: `IIF` Is syntactic sugar for a `CASE` expression, which OP doesn't want (though their reasoning seems off)

Comment: so this should work but apparently iif was taken out after sql 2012. Yeah @HoneyBadger is right, i was looking for the most syntactically sugary way of doing it

Comment: `declare @t int = 1

select iif (@t = 0, 1, @t)`
returns `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

Comment: @r_mat, it doesn't for me on sql server 2016

Comment: @HoneyBadger my bad i meant SSMS 2012

Comment: SSMS is just a GUI for sql server. What version of sql server do you have (`SELECT @@VERSION`)?

Comment: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp) shows that `iif()` is available from SQL server 2012

Comment: whoops i am operating on bad information from a friend which i didnt fact check, it was meant to be [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540753/sql-server-2008-iif-statement-does-not-seem-enabled) 2012 on sql - i am working on 2008

Comment: @r_mat, Then simply use a `CASE` expression. Personally, I find it much easier to read anyway.